# In a 12 factor app, how should metrics be sent to the metrics monitoring server?

Tags: metrics, 12factor

The 12 factor app manifesto recommends [writing all log output to stdout](http://12factor.net/logs). This is extremely easy to achieve if your service/app runs in a docker container. You can then use a docker log driver to have the logs sent to a log shipper like fluentd, which can then send them to elasticsearch for analysis or something like HDFS for long term storage.

While it is very clear how logs are to be handled, there doesn't seem to be any guidance on how to handle metrics. For example, we might want to track the time spent on each request, error rates and other things for our service.

It's possible to have the service send metrics directly, but it seems to be a violation of the 12 factor app principles. In addition, if the metrics server goes down, or the service goes down, we would need to deal with writing the metrics to disk and other write-ahead-log-like features which increases the complexity.

A possible solution would be to write metrics to `stdout` and have fluentd filter them. But in this case we are mixing the logs and the metrics, and we would need to either have a set format for what logs and metrics look like to differentiate them, and this may not be an option for services that are not written by us.

In a 12 factor app, how should metrics from an app/service be sent to the metrics server?

Answer (score 0):

The metrics server is not really any different from any other dependencies, e.g. database or whatever. Dependency locations are configured through environment variables (http://12factor.net/config), so use that to pass in where the app should send its metrics.

The issue with metrics service going down is probably out-of-scope for the configuration.  How the application handles one of its dependencies not being available is really more of an application design issue. You can choose to buffer a certain amount in RAM or on some sort of ephemeral filesystem, or just drop anything which can't be sent - your choice.  The point is that the location is configured for that environment, anything else is a design issue.

Just my 2c, HTH.